# O que significa o ponto-e-vírgula no início da linha?

Tags: javascript

Estava a analisar um código e encontrei o seguinte trecho:

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    //...
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Repare que no início da primeira linha, existe o carácter ";" (ponto e vírgula).
Qual a função do ponto-e-vírgula no início da linha?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A função do ponto e vírgula no inicio da linha é concatenar correctamente um novo código quando o anterior não inclui o ";" no final.

```
var n = a + b 
(c + d).print()
```

Sem a vírgula, a segunda linha teria sido interpretada como uma chamada de função. 
O sistema interpretaria da seguinte forma:

```
var n = a + b(c + d).print();
```

Repare que a variável "b" passaria a ser interpretada como uma função, retornando o seguinte erro:

```
ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

Concluindo, é boa prática terminar sempre uma instrução com o ";", porém quando uma linha começar com parênteses é também boa prática precede-lo com o ";", principalmente quando temos necessidade de alterar código de terceiros.

```
;(c + d).print()
```

Comment: `"Concluindo, quando uma linha começar com parênteses é boa prática precede-lo com o ";"."` Não. Boa prática é fazer como o mundo inteiro faz (vide JSLint e JSHint), e colocar o ponto-e-vírgula no lugar certo, que é no final da expressão imediatamente anterior à que começa com parênteses. Recomendo ler *Maintanable Javascript*, de Nicholas C. Zaka.

Comment: @Renan conheço o livro. Lógico que é boa prática terminar a instrução com o ";", porém me deparei com isso em alguns códigos mesmo contendo o ";" no fim da instrução. De qualquer forma alterei a conclusão.